# How to change server name on Wordpress Installation?

Tags: links, server, apache

I am not sure if the title of the question is acurate enough but here it goes.

I have set up an Ubuntu server inside a VirtualBox VM, I have enabled port forwarding so when I type on the host `localhost:8888` it gets forwarded to the apache running on the guest. I have also set up port forwarding in my router (BT Home Hub) so when e request on the public IP (81.153.xxx.xxx) comes on port 8888 it gets again forwarded to the apache on the guest.

All is fine up to now, but my problem comes when I want to cross-browser test in a service like [browseling](http://browserling.com/). It opens the home page fine (sadly all my images and stylesheets are not loaded) but when I click on different links it gives a 404. After investigating this I found that Wordpress uses absolute links that are, in my case, in the format of `http://localhost:8888/category/test-category/`, and of course they would not show up when the request is made from the outside. Now I do not have a domain name because this is a server purely for testing and development purposes but I would really like to be able to use browserling for testing it and thus I need the links to use the public IP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add your port `8888` under *general settings* wordpress/site url, or directly in your config.php. In your case that would be `http://localhost:8888` . I don't know how or what browseling  is but a quick glance also shows they support ssh reverse tunnel proxy for localhost, which is another option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Wyck but my problem is not with the ports, its more like the fact that if you type in your browser my public IP address now (81.153.xxx.xxx) you'll have access to my blog, but all the images and stylesheets would not be loaded, because they have to be loaded from `localhost/path/to/them` and clearly you don't have them on your local host, this is also true for my links to categories and posts. I want to make this linking that says local host to say 81.153.xxx.xxx/path/to/something or ultimately in some other way to make it accessible from outside. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: There nothing WordPress can do if you don't correctly set the pathing.

Comment: Fair enough, how can I change the pathing from the current one to one that is correct. I mean how would I change a path that is `localhost/style.css` to `correct.com/style.css` or in my case `81.153.xxx.xxx/style.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to @Wyck, I found a sollution to what I wanted to do. I'll try to explain here. The problem was that I needed to change two values found under Dashboard -> Settings -> General Configuration. These values were "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" I changed them (I got a no-ip domain so I can test easier) and I managed to access my blog from outside my LAN. Fair enough but I couldn't access from the inside, to do that I edited my `hosts` file on Windows and added this line:
`127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com`.